# How to access an array within an object within an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

EDIT: Since my question has been closed due to being considered too similar to other question already answered, I decided to edit it and try to be more specific. Also, I considered what the people that kindly commented my original question said and adapted the text accordingly.

Let's start with the context to the question:

I'm creating a movie quiz about a director I really like. The ideia is to try to predict what is one's favorite movie of this director based on the answers one gives to some "yes or no" questions. In the  first part of the quiz, the person taking it will select which movies from this director the person has already watched.

So to start with there is an empty array called **movies** that will be filled with the movies the person selects from a list. These movies are listed below the array as objects:

```
const movies = [];

const movie1 = {
  name: "movie1",
  keywords: ["black-and-white", "independent"],
  points: 0
};

const movie2 = {
  name: "movie2",
  keywords: ["black-and-white", "independent"],
  points: 0
};

const movie3 = {
  name: "movie3",
  keywords: ["color", "studio production"],
  points: 0
};

const movie4 = {
  name: "movie4",
  keywords: ["superhero", "blockbuster"],
  points: 0
};
```

Obs: all the movie objects have the property **keywords**, and this property is always an array with more than one value (thanks to **Phil** for clearing my doubt about it being an array or not!).

Obs2: to answer the commenter **redwards**, I can say the thing you refer to in your comment was a really typo from my part when posting the code here in the question. Now I posted the code as it is originally. There is no ";" in the way to mess it up. But thanks for noticing it. I can see how that could have been a problem.

I managed to create the logic that adds the movies to the array **movies** like this:

```
function addMovie(movieName){
movies.push(movieName)
return
};

document.getElementById("movieFollowing").addEventListener("click", function() {
  addMovie(movie1);
});
```

This works fine. The problem I have is once each movie object is inside the array **movies**.

How can I access the property **keywords** of each movie object inside the array **movies**? How can I confirm whether the **keywords** property contains a specific value inside of it?

For example, one of the questions of the quiz is to check if the person enjoys black-and-white movies. If yes, then all the movie objects inside the array that have the keyword "black-and-white" inside the property **keywords** would get 1 point. If no, then they would get -1 point.

I came up with a code that almost solves this problem:

```
function addPoints(keyWord) {
for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
if (movies[i].keywords == keyWord) {
movies[i].points++}
else {
  movies[i].points--
}
}
};

document.getElementById("questionOneYes").addEventListener("click", function () {
  addPoints("black-and-white")
});
```

The code above works perfectly if the property **keywords** has only one value. But it doesn't work if it has more than one, like I intend it to be.

I tried to treat the **keywords** property like an array and to access it through the *includes()* method:

```
function addPoints(keyWord) {
for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
if (movies[i].keywords.includes(keyWord)) {
movies[i].points++}
else {
  movies[i].points--
}
}
};
```

It didn't work. I got this error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')"

So, please help. There must be a way to make this work, otherwise I'll have to create many properties in every object, each with a different keyword, and then more than one function to access each of these different keyword properties... and that sounds like too many lines of code for something that should be simpler and more concise to make.

Comment: _"is "keywords" an array itself"_... yes 

Comment: As for your error, I would guess that not all of your `movies` entries have a `keywords` property. You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to access it safely, eg `movies[i].keywords?.includes(keyWord)`

Comment: For what it's worth, although this was closed, I believe the actual issue was the json array rows being separated by ';' instead of ','.  I loaded the code and ran it without issue once making that change.

Comment: @Phil thank you very for answering my question about 'keywords' being an array or not! The optional chaining you suggested also appears to solve the problem I was facing as well, even though I couldn't understand exactly what the "?." does. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @redwards The ";" was a typo when I tried to rewrite my code here. It wasn't in the original post, so I wasn't something that was interfering. But thanks for noticing. I corrected it and tried to reopen the question, but in the end Phil's suggestion seems to solve my problems.

Comment: _"I couldn't understand exactly what the "?." does"_... did you read the documentation I linked?

Comment: I confess to not have read it with the due attention, since I was just trying to find a clear explanation that referred to what I was having to deal with expecificly. I reread the documentation now. Although my situation is not explicitly covered by the documentation's examples, I think is fair to say that I can understand how the optional chaining works in the context of my code now.